# mega-menu using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a "mega menu" using nested `<ul>` within a `<li>`. Using jQuery (mouseover) on the parent `<li>`, I can make `<ul class="sec1"` and `<ul class="sec2">` appear.

But the mouseout on `li` doesn't work because the drop down disappears as soon as you rollout of the parent `<li>`. How can I keep the drop down active if the mouse is over the parent `<li>` or either child `<ul>`?

HTML structure below.

```
<li>link
 <ul class="sec1">
  <li>sub-link1</li>
  ......
  <li>sub-link5</li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="sec2">
  <li>sub-link1</li>
  ......
  <li>sub-link5</li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

thanks

Comment: Where are you having trouble? What browser? I can't reproduce this using http://jsfiddle.net/vMPRa/ (the menu stays open while over any sub menu)

Comment: thanks. your jQuery seems to work. I was using separate functions for show and hide. can i accept a comment as an answer?

Comment: @Robert - do you want to post your JQeury as an answer?

Comment: Nah that's fine, if it's working, good to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to build a *suckerfish-style menu*, you should try the [hoverIntent plugin](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) or better yet, use the [Superfish plugin](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) that has support for it.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the mega menu from closing when you hover the descendant elements inside the parent `li` you should use the `mousemove` event.
Here is the exmample that I created for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/imalitavakoli/bpmyu1sb/2/

And you may also consider using this jQuery plugin and CSS framework: https://myflashlabs.github.io/24component-bars/

Here is also its mega menu example:
https://myflashlabs.github.io/24component-bars/previews/nav-03.html

It helps you create responsive mega menu, header, sidebar, and footer with lots functionalities fast and easy, without any hassle... It's exactly what you want :)

You don't need to code it yourself all from the beginning when there's already a solution out there!